# Redshift - Missing latest date when join two tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables (Calling as A and B table);

Table - A data only includes the last 1 month data.
Table - B data stores all data that you have.

```
|user | table_A_date | amount_table_A|
|-----| ------------ | ------------- |
| A   |2019-11-30    |1111.0         |
| A   |2019-12-02    |1111.0         |
| A   |2019-12-05    |1111.0         |
| A   |2019-12-09    |1111.0         |


|user | table_B_date | amount_table_B|
|-----| ------------ | ------------- |
| A   |2019-11-25    |1111.0         |
| A   |2019-12-02    |1111.0         |
| A   |2019-12-05    |1111.0         |
| A   |2019-12-10    |1111.0         |
```

I need to find the difference between these two tables dates, but when I left joined the two tables I have null dates:

```
|user     | table_A_date |  table_B_date | amount_table_A|
| ------- | -------      | -------       | -----   |
| A       |2019-11-30    |   Null        |1111.0   |
| A       |2019-12-02    |2019-12-02     |1111.0   |
| A       |2019-12-05    |2019-12-05     |1111.0   |
| A       |2019-12-09    |    Null       |1111.0   |
```

I am going to use `last_value over ()` function but I am still missing the first `null` value. How can I store each user previous last value `(for user A 2019-11-25`)

Comment: Axis, are lookng for the rows in A not in B and in B not in A? I am a little confused

Comment: Hi @zip, thank you for comment. I need to have the most recent data (only the date )stored in table B but out of table A

Comment: With the example posted can you show the expected results please? We will be able to answer right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `full join` along with `lag()`/`last_value()` and then filter:

```
select ab.*
from (select coalesce(a.user, b.user) as user,
             a.date as a_date, a.amount as a_amount,
             coalesce(b.date,
                      lag(b.date ignore nulls) over (partition by user order by b.date)
                         ) as b_date,
             coalesce(b.amount,
                      lag(b.amount ignore nulls) over (partition by user order by b.date)
                     ) as b_amount
      from a full join
           b
           on a.user = b.user and a.date = b.date
     ) ab
where a_date is not null;
```

Comment: @Axis . . . Good question.  I actually had to think about this one.